# Why is the HTTP answer different for different user agents? (Spring Security OAuth2 Token Endpoint)

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

When sending a request to an OAuth2 Token Endpoint, the RFC says, the response has to be in JSON format. When using Spring Security, strange things happen however. To be sure, the fault isn't in my code, I used the demo app Sparklr2 to test the following. The problem is, that depending on the user agent I use, the result is different.

I access the url `http://localhost:8084/sparklr2/oauth/token`

If I use curl, Advanced REST Client, telnet or similar, the result is just as expected:

```
{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}
```

If I however user Firefox or Chrome I get an answer in XML format:

```
<oauth><error_description>Full authentication is required to access this resource</error_description><error>unauthorized</error></oauth>
```

Why does this strange behaviour happen?

Comment: Spring probably honors the `Accept` header. Btw I have found this - https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-richer-oauth-xml-01#section-4.1 .

Comment: That sounds right. Using `Accept: application/xml` gives the same answer as in Firefox/Chrome. I am wondering if this behaviour is right. But anyway, it won't really matter as clients won't be asking for an xml answer, I was just wondering that it looked wrong when first trying it in a browser.

Comment: @PavelHoral Regarding your edited comment: Oh, I didn't know about this draft, so after all, you can't reproach Spring any wrong behavior then at all. Turn your comment into an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring probably honors the `Accept` header. Browsers usually send `application/xml` as an accepted format. REST clients usually include `application/json`. CURL does not send anything (unless you define it) and Spring probably prefers the JSON in such case.

As for the format itself I have found this - https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-richer-oauth-xml-01#section-4.1 .